# The best practice for high write/read between nodes in a JAVA distributed system

Tags: performance, caching, redis, distributed, infinispan

I have a Java-based distributed system with 3 to 5 nodes on different machines that support 1500 TPS, and we need to share data between these nodes in each transaction, meaning that one node writes data to a source and another node retrieves it.
Does anyone have experience with the best practice for high write/read between nodes in a JAVA distributed systems?

Currently, I have used Infinispan cache, but unfortunately, its performance deteriorates significantly as soon as multiple nodes are added.

Comment: You asked this question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77316080/problem-of-performance-in-replicated-infinispan?rq=2 but you failed to follow up with the required information.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I edited my previous question.